# Use google volley to receive streaming data

Tags: android-volley

I am trying to use volley to receive streaming strings. The api works well with curl command or HttpURLConnection:

```
curl http://streamingurl.com // fake url

string-piece1 string-piece2 string-piece3...
```

After you make such a request, the server just keep feeding you string pieces about every second.

However when I try it with Volley it doesn't work:

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://streamingurl.com",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("Streaming", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Streaming", error.toString());
                    }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I expect to receive a string snippet every second in the console. However I didn't. I just receive a TimeoutError after several second. Is it possible to use Volley to receive the streaming strings?

Comment: Hey! Any solution for the same?

Comment: @VinilNarang Actually in android documentation it says volley is not suitable for streaming: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html. And actually if you read volley source code you will find it is not possible at all. I just use httpurlconnection to do the streaming at the end.

Comment: Even I ended up using httpUrlConnection.